# Error with RViz

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have indigo ros and I downloaded moveit to work with the graphical interface rviz, but when I want to save some state of the robot, a message says: "Not connected to a database. The state will be created but not stored".
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232958/error-with-rviz/) by [Anapascual](https://answers.ros.org/users/26711/anapascual/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on 2017-05-06**:
Same problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out how to fix this problem for me:

1. Follow install steps for the ros warehouse http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/dependencies/.
2. (You might not need this depending on your version of moveit) Make the changes in this pull request locally to fix moveit https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/81/files.
3. Launch the ros warehouse! `roslaunch <YOUR_GENERATED_moveit_config>/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch` I got this file from the moveit setup wizard.

---

Originally posted by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) with karma: 203 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt has a database interface termed "warehouse", but this is not active by default because you need to run a database somewhere.
At the moment, the only working implementation I'm aware of is https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros_mongo .

So if you want to store your robot states or planning scenes, you will have to setup a MongoDB and use this plugin.

Note that if you only want to store a small number of states, you can do that [in the srdf file of your moveit_config](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/tams_ur5_setup/blob/master/tams_ur5_setup_moveit_config/config/tams_ur5_setup.srdf#L31). The setup assistant also provides a panel to add these states there.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1